# Can't connect to specific domain from ec2 linux instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect from an ec2 micro instance to the following domain: http://www.bnm.gov.my but it seems to be blocked.

I have tried doing a simple request using curl.

```
curl http://www.bnm.gov.my
```

which gives me the following error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.bnm.gov.my port 80: Connection timed out
```

I tried wget

```
 wget http://www.bnm.gov.my
```

and get the following error:

```
--2018-10-31 14:33:06--  http://www.bnm.gov.my/
Resolving www.bnm.gov.my (www.bnm.gov.my)... 103.6.236.129
Connecting to www.bnm.gov.my (www.bnm.gov.my)|103.6.236.129|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

Also, a traceroute times out.

I can access the website from my computer as well as websites like downforeveryoneorjustme dot com and uptrends to check if there are any issues with the website but it seems to be my amazon instance.

I have access to internet, I can request other websites using curl... but this particular one isn't working...

I appreciate any ideas you may have as to how to fix this!

Current ACL Configuration for VPC. (The instance is running within a VPC)

```
Outbound

Rule #  Type    Protocol    Port Range  Destination Allow/Deny
100 All IPv4 traffic all      all       0.0.0.0/0    ALLOW
*   All IPv4 traffic all      all       0.0.0.0/0    DENY
```

Comment: What happens when you increase the curl timeout? curl --max-time 30  http://www.bnm.gov.my

Comment: it gives me the following error: `curl: (28) Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds`

Comment: and does it work using `wget`?

Comment: no, it also gives me a time out. (i'm updating the original question to include that result as well) thanks for the recommendation

Comment: Did you check that your outbound rules in your security group allow reaching that domain? I just went into one of my Linux instances in EC2 and was able to use `wget http://www.bnm.gov.my`.

Comment: One possibility, though unlikely, is that the BNM website is blackholing traffic from certain IP ranges, including parts of EC2.

Comment: my outbound rules are fine. Yeah... that's the only thing i can think of. (them blackholing traffic from my ip)

Comment: Are you running your instance within a vpc? Does your vpc have a newtwork acl associated with that ip?

Comment: yes, it is running withing a VPC. It has the default ACL configuration. (I added the configuration info to the end of the original post)

Comment: It is working from an Amazon EC2 instance I have in Sydney (ap-southeast-2) region. Can you wget from another website to confirm it is just `bnm` causing the problem?